# Regex for both currency iso code and symbol

Tags: ruby, regex

I am trying to find exact currency match with currency iso codes or symbols. I've got a list of currencies and symbols, which in regex I just use `(USD|JPY)` and `$|£|` etc for example. So criteria are:

1. Should be an exact match for a currency code `USD` `JPY` or symbol `$` `£`. Currency codes are case insensitive
2. Before and after can have an optional number
3. There can only be a number before and after the currency (can contain whitespace in between).

Example:
`a = 4USD - $3 + a4 USD / JPY    400 * 3USDa`

Output would be (provided `.scan` called in ruby): `["USD", "$", "USD", "JPY"]`

Incorrect would be to include `3USDa`

I've been trying a lot of patterns to no avail, here some of them:

`/\d+(?=(USD|JPY)(?!\w))|(USD|JPY)(?=\d+(?!\w))/i`

`/(?<=(JPY|USD))*\d|(?<=\d)(JPY|USD)/i`

Comment: So what's the output you want from your string?

Comment: Shouldn't `$` be in the correct matches of your example, too?

Comment: And, why is `bob 4 USD` invalid? You said "can't contain anything else straight after" (and presumably also straight before), but the `bob` is *not* "straight before"; it's separated by a space.

Comment: Also, how do you know `$` is `USD` and not `CAD`? Both use the same symbol

Comment: @ctwheels 1) I am expecting the exact matches and I kinda jumped a step in my correct matches. It should actually be ['USD', '$', 'JPY']. Sorry about that.

2) This is something I'll address later, I have currency priority and currently just default to USD if its $. I will give the ability to set symbol to currency if there are multiple. Outside of scope here though

Comment: @TomLord 1) My mistake as outlined in the other answer, it should indeed be USD $ JPY. 2) Ok, my conditions were a bit wrong, I'll update the question. To be exact I allow only operators in between, so this is valid: 'bob + 4 USD', but this is invalid 'bob 4 USD', as if there are no operators, I consider this as one group: 'bob4USD'.

Comment: Is `"$4USD"` valid? What about `"$4 USD5"`? What about `"123£456"`? What about `"$4.50"`? I can't help but feel you're going to update the requirements again, if I actually provide an answer to the current logic...

Comment: @TomLord Sorry, this is quite mindboggling for me as well, I spent months trying to improve this. Perhaps it would be easier to think of this not as entire string, but array. I already use `.split` to separate the string, so say you'll get `["a", "=", "$4", "USD5", "+", "123£456"]`  If there is a whitespace, say for `$4 USD5`. So regex is applied in isolation. But thinking about this again, perhaps I'll keep only first part of 3rd requirement, otherwise, it's too much to make a sensible regex.

Comment: @TomLord So as long as there are only numbers around, its a match. So `a4USD` would be a match,  but not `aUSD4`

Comment: @TomLord Sorry about changing the requirements twice, I've been stuck on this problem for months and it still makes little sense to me. Being able to decypher free text input is a nightmare...

Comment: @MaximFedotov Why not just provide a larger, "realistic", sample of the data input and show all the fields you want to match? I'm still very much unconvinced by your requirements; I'd rather just deal with the raw data. Maybe open a new SO question, as it's not good practice to totally change the requirements 2 or 3 times after asking ;)

Comment: @TomLord Problem is I only have mostly my own data sample and I keep on finding new instances when I play around with the app. "realistic" would have been getting users input on this, but I wanted to get this sorted before I get people to try it out. But I agree, I'll make a new question with my own integration test data and try to really boil down the requirements.

Comment: Which currency strings match this string: `"4USD JPS 33$ £"`?

Comment: @CarySwoveland It would have been [`USD`, `$`, `£`]. But nevermind that, I've found a gem combination that makes a much better job at string parsing then trying to do it with a single regex. So I am closing this question for good

Comment: You don't need to close it, as others may find it interesting. You may wish to mention the specific gem combination you used in a comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're OK using the capture group rather than the overall match, then the following is perhaps the simplest regex solution to your requirements:

```
/(?<!\w)\d*\s*(JPY|USD|\$|£)\s*\d*(?!\w)/i
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/ug0qdX/2)

If you have a list of all currencies, you could construct that regex programmatically like:

```
currencies = %w(USD JPN $ £)
currencies_pattern = currencies.map {|c| Regexp.escape(c) }.join("|")
full_pattern = /(?<!\w)\d*\s*(#{currencies_pattern})\s*\d*(?!\w)/i
```

As commented above, not that this **does** return `$` as a valid match from your example. Based on my understanding of your rules, I don't see why `$` should be considered a non-match.